# How to save multiple dates in Firebase database so that admin can keep track of orders on a particular date

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, datepicker

```
final Date today = new Date();
Calendar nextYear = Calendar.getInstance();
nextYear.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);

CalendarPickerView datePicker = findViewById(R.id.calendarPickerView);
datePicker.init(today, nextYear.getTime()).withSelectedDate(today);

datePicker.setOnDateSelectedListener(new CalendarPickerView.OnDateSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateSelected(Date date) {
        Calendar calselected = Calendar.getInstance();
        calselected.setTime(date);

        final String selectedDate = "" + 
        calselected.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/" + 
        (calselected.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "/" + 
        calselected.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        String user_uid = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        final DatabaseReference current_user_db = mDatabase.child(user_uid);

        alterupdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View view) {
                 current_user_db.child("Altered date").setValue(selectedDate);
                 startActivity(new Intent(first_activity.this, second_activity.class));
             }
        });
    }
});
```

I created calendar picker and saved the output in "Altered date" field. But when a user selects other date it is overriding the current date. So, what is the best option to save all the altered dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But when a user selects other date it is overriding the current date.

This is happening because you are calling `set()` method on the same reference. Since every node in a Firebase database is a `Map` and in case of `Map`, it replaces the old value with the new one.

> So, what is the best option to save all the altered dates?

To solve this, I recommend you to use the `push()` method. For that, please change the followig line of code:

```
current_user_db.child("Altered date").setValue(selectedDate);
```

to

```
current_user_db.child("Altered date").push().setValue(selectedDate);
```

Comment: Thanks. It is saving the list of altered dates. but when user clicks on update button ,there is also an option to select the quantity of an item from spinner. is there any way to link the quantity and selected date ?